# tensorflow-gpu error | Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel | status: Internal: invalid device function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0

```
2020-02-10 18:56:03.997155: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:06.902771: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:07.849352: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:<br>
name: GeForce GTX 1650 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.56
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:07.855482: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-02-10 18:56:07.860526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:07.863861: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-02-10 18:56:07.880373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:<br>
name: GeForce GTX 1650 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.56<br>
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:07.886459: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-02-10 18:56:07.891278: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:08.001331: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:08.005924: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:08.008184: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:08.011837: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3023 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)<br>
2020-02-10 18:56:08.154262: F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:227] <b>Non-OK-status: <br>GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: invalid device function</b>
```

I am getting this error while running keras LSTM code. The code is correct. 
Believe me I have all possible configurations to install tensorflow-gpu but it is not working.
i installed this one by: 
making new env
`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu`

i have also tried by installing Cudnn and CUDA toolkit seperately but same thing appears. 
CPU : i7 9th gen
GPU : GTX 1650
LAPTOP : ASUS G STRIX g531GT 2019

Someone please help me, i have wasted 5-10 hours trying every possible configuration.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68054463/14337775