# Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(..) status: Internal: out of memory in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have a module which contains base-class

```
class MessagePassing(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__():
        super(MessagePassing, self).__init__()
        ....
    def call():
        ....
```

I'm importing the base class in  another module

```
from module1 import MessgagePassing

class layer(MessagePassing):
    def __init__(self, in, out):
        super(layer, self).__init__()
        self.W = self.add_weight("w", shape=[in, out], initializer="glorot_uniform")
        ....
```

When the above module is complied, it raises an error

```
2021-06-20 14:42:23.392722: F ./tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] 
Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) 
status: Internal: out of memory
```

I ran the code using vscode in debug mode and found that pointer-to-breakpoint stops twice at `self.add_weight`. Following which it throws error after considerable time lapse.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to reproduce the same error with Sublime Text, so I switched to it. Surprisingly, the code started working as intended.

However, I wonder why this might be happening?